# Python - using returns in conditional statements

Tags: python, return

I want to use return instead of print statements but when I replace the print statements with return I don't get anything back. I know I'm missing something obvious:

```
def consecCheck(A):
    x = sorted(A)
    for i in enumerate(x):
        if i[1] == x[0]:
            continue
        print x[i[0]], x[i[0]-1]
        p = x[i[0]] - x[i[0]-1]
        print p
        if p > 1:
            print "non-consecutive"
            break
        elif x[i[0]] == len(x):
            print "consecutive"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    consecCheck([1,2,3,5])
```

-----UPDATE------ HERE IS CORRECTED CODE AFTER TAKING HEATH3N's answer:

```
def consecCheck(A):
    x = sorted(A)
    for i in enumerate(x):
        if i[1] == x[0]:
            continue
        print x[i[0]], x[i[0]-1]
        p = x[i[0]] - x[i[0]-1]
        print p
        if p > 1:
            a = "non-consecutive"
            break
        elif x[i[0]] == len(x):
            a = "consecutive"
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print consecCheck([4,3,7,1,5])
```

Comment: Why do you think `return` will print anything? That's not what it does.

Comment: Also, return breaks out of the function, and doesn't come back. If you want to return and continue execution, use `yield`.

Comment: Add your expected result to better clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand what a return statement does:

> A return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine and resume at the point in the code immediately after where the subroutine was called, known as its return address.

You need to wrap `consecCheck([1,2,3,5])` in a print statement. Otherwise, all it does it call the function (which no longer prints anything) and goes back to what it was doing.

Comment: @ HEATH3N Yes, you are right. Still having issues understanding return. I put in the corrected code above. I just wanted a way to ensure that a dichotomous value was being captured by the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`print` takes python object and outputs a printed representation to console/output window

when `return` statement used in function execution of program to calling location, also if function execution reaches to return statement then no other line will be executed. read detail [difference between print and return](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pip2/Functions/Printvs.return.html)

So In your case if you want to show result in output console you may do it as following example:

```
def my_function():
    # your code
    return <calculated-value>
val = my_function()
print(val) # so you can store return value of function in `val` and then print it or you can just directly write print(my_function())
```

In your code you are printing values and continuing execution in that case you might consider using `yield` keyword suggested by @COLDSPEED or just use `print` to all statement except last one

Comment: Thanks. I used HEATH3N's solution but this was very informative. I'm still having trouble with the yield statement but will continue to research.